# Heat transfer from air (at ambient temp.) to a liquid in an open container

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

I’m designing a bath which should keep the temperature of the liquid inside (transformer oil) at a constant temperature (approx. 20 °C).

I have calculated the amount of energy needed to heat up the volume of liquid inside, however due to the bath having an open top, I also want to take into consideration the effect of ambient temperature. (the bath is small, so I'm worried that ambient temperature will affect its performance)

I know I should probably consider a simple model for this, as I don't want to over complicate by considering a lot of parameters.

By assuming that the air above the container is a reservoir whose temperature is constant and is in thermal contact with the surface of the liquid, would considering heat transfer through convection be enough?

Since the setup would be inside a laboratory, conditions should be stable enough (such as air velocity and humidity).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convective heat transfer coefficient equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127546)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low bath temperature of $20\text{°C}$ implies that radiation losses can be considered negligible and *convection is the main mechanism for heat transfer*.

In that case, you probably want to consider [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Heat_transfer_version_of_the_law) (which incidentally works also for heating):

$$\dot{q}=-hA(T_{bath}-T_{amb})$$

where:

- $\dot{q}$ is the heat flux (flowing from the bath to the environment)
- $T_{bath}$ is the bath's temperature. It is assumed to be uniform throughout the bath
- $T_{amb}$ is the surroundings' temperature (considered constant)
- $A$ is the surface area of the bath exposed to the environment
- $h$ is the **convection heat transfer coefficient** (generally considered to be a constant)

If the bath has constant mass $m$ and the liquid has a heat capacity $c_p$ then the law can be rewritten slightly to:

$$mc_p\frac{\text{d}T_{bath}}{\text{d}t}=-hA(T_{bath}-T_{amb})$$

---

One interesting application is finding the temperature evolution of the bath in time. Lets write $T_{bath}$ as $T(t)$ and $k=\frac{hA}{mc_p}$, so:

$$\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=-k(T(t)-T_{amb})$$

This is a simple differential equation that solves by separation of variables to:

$$\ln\Big({\frac{T(t)-T_{amb}}{T_0-T_{amb}}}\Big)=-kt$$
where $T_0$ is the bath temperature at $t=0$.

Rewritten we get:

$$\boxed{T(t)=T_{amb}+(T_0-T_{amb})\exp{(-kt)}}$$